# Elixir SOAP (detergentex) with client ssl certificate

Tags: soap, ssl-certificate, elixir

We (myself and my dev team) are relatively new to Elixir, especially after successfully porting large parts of our API service to Elixir with great results.

However, we're having an issue getting connected to an upstream SOAP WebService that requires an SSL Client certificate. The wrapper library **detergentex** seems to be the only real available library for consuming web services, however I cannot find a way to make use of Client SSL certificates in the request, which is required by our service provider.

We currently make use of SUDS in Python to achieve this, however porting to Elixir will have tremendous benefits for parallelisation of these particular requests.

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: did you get this working in the end?

Comment: I got it partially working but there were further problems with the detergent library in Erlang that prevented the Web Service's WSDL from being consumed -- in particular the WebService had imports which were not being included. In the end, I just used HTTPoison with Hackneye and and parsed the XML using an XML library explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like detergentex itself doesn't support it, but the Erlang library it wraps, [detergent](https://github.com/devinus/detergent/), looks like it would support it.

The function `detergent:call` [can be called with an optional fourth argument](https://github.com/devinus/detergent/blob/master/src/detergent.erl#L113-L129), a `#call_opts{}` record. This record is defined in [detergent.hrl](https://github.com/devinus/detergent/blob/master/include/detergent.hrl) and contains a field called `http_client_options`. In detergent.erl, this record eventually ends up being passed to one of two HTTP clients: it chooses [ibrowse](https://github.com/cmullaparthi/ibrowse) if that's available, and otherwise uses [httpc](http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html) from the built-in inets application.

For httpc, you can pass SSL options as a `{ssl, [...]}` tuple in `http_client_options`, while ibrowse expects the tuple to be `{ssl_options, [...]}`, so you need to know which HTTP client detergent will use in order to pass the right option.

The SSL options are described in the [ssl man page](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ssl.html).  To set a client certificate, pass the options `{certfile, "/path/to/client.cert"}` and `{keyfile, "/path/to/client.key"}`. If the certificate and the private key are in the same file, you can omit the `keyfile` option.

It shouldn't be hard to add support for this to detergentex, or you could call detergent directly from Elixir.